# Delete / change values in a column based on values in a different column in R

Tags: r

It seems I cannot get to the bottom of one issue and I haven't found a satisfactory answer anywhere.

So, here is my problem. I have a data frame with multiple columns and I want to change the values in one column if the value matches a string in another column.

For example:

```
id  Var1    Var2 .................Var10
 1   A                              1
 2   A                              1
 3   D            
     R
     F         .
     .  
1000 A                              1
```

What I want to achieve ultimately is to change values in Column 10 to another value of my choice if values in Column 1 match a declared value. As an example, if value in column 1 is "A", then change value in Column 10 to NA.

I have tried to use this code, but failed:

```
if(df$Var1 = "A"){df$Var10 <- "NA"}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$Var10[df$Var1=="A"] <- "NA"
```